# How to import and call a react pure function which is using redux connect and its functions? (Only React functional components no classes)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

Suppose I have a react pure function named `SignIn()` in One.js :

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {GoogleSignin, statusCodes} from '@react-native-community/google-signin';
import {getToken, saveToken} from '../actions/token';

const SignIn = async ({token, getToken, saveToken}) => {
  const savedToken = await getToken();
  console.log(token.loading, savedToken);

  SignIn.propTypes = {
    token: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    getToken: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    saveToken: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  };
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  console.log('state : ', state);
  return {
    token: state.token,
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {saveToken, getToken})(SignIn);
```

I want to use this `SignIn()` function in another Two.js react file so that `getToken()` which is a redux function and other functions will be called inside file One.js and then i can use those functions inside file Two.js but the problem is because of redux connect, i am not able to export and use them. How can i import and use this kind of function inside Two.js file ?

Answer (score 2):

`connect` function can only be implemented with react components that renders actual `jsx`, and for it to work you need to return `jsx elements` or `null` and call it like this `<SignIn />`.. in my opinion if you want to implement some logic with the use of `redux`, you can make a `custom hook`, implement `useSelector` or `useDispatch` inside it, and either `return` the data you want or just do your `effect` inside it then return nothing.

hope this helps.

here's an example from `react-redux` docs https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#usedispatch

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Actually I am using redux thunk which has a action of getToken :  export const getToken = () => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
    console.log('got token : ', token);

    dispatch({
      type: GET_TOKEN,
      payload: token,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};  so if i only use dispatch then Asyncstorage.getItem will not get executed, this is the problem, maybe i should try to get the SignIn Function by creating its reducer and actions that might work

Comment: there's no problem using useDispatch with redux-thunk, you can do it like this
const dispatch = useDispatch();
useEffect(() => {
dispatch(getToken());
},[])

then with useSelector you do it like this: const {token} = useSelector((state) => ({token: state.reducer.token}))

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, i tried to use it but i was getting hooks can only be called inside a functional component but i was calling inside a functional component, what worked for me was using the functions inside redux actions.

Answer (score 0):

What Worked for me was declaring the functions that i want to export inside the redux actions, so i created a new action for any function that i want to use. Make sure to make use of loading state of initial state otherwise functions can be called infinite times because of re-rendering.